# Unable to make facebook Audience for subtype STUDY_AUDIENCE, permission error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, post, get

So I am not able to create facebook audience for subtype STUDY_AUDIENCE

Here is what I have done so far:

I followed up the documentation of Audience API for Audience Insights.
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/audiences-api/audience-insights-study/v2.6
Now I went to graph explorer,
made a post request to this URL for creating study audience:

```
act_<account id>/customaudiences
```

with following parameters:

```
name =  whateverName
subtype = STUDY_AUDIENCE
study_spec = {"start_time":1462434200,"end_time":1492433600,"audience_definition":{"genders":["male"],"age_brackets":[ "18-24","25-34"],"countries":["US"]},"included_rules":[{"update_type":"NEW","rule_components":[{"type":"any_of","contents":["breakfast","chicken"]}]}]}
```

Then it gave me error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "message": "(#200) Permissions error",
    "type": "OAuthException",
    "code": 200,
    "fbtrace_id": "some_trace_id"
  }
}
```

I have given all permissions to my facebook app, I am using user access token, and it works fine on other audience subtypes, don't know why it is not working for this one.

Making get request on this URL:

```
act_<account id>/customaudiences
```

returns audiences created by me, and it works fine.

So why its not working for `subtype = STUDY_AUDIENCE` ? I am the owner of the app, owner of the business and owner of everything related to facebook app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've had a similar problem. My Ad account didn't have the feature enabled.

At the current time Audience Insights Studies aren't publicly available so the feature needs to be enabled, by facebook, for both your Ad account *and* your app.

Comment: Hello,
Reviving this question. Do you know if this API endpoint is still valid (given that v2.6 is deprecated?)
Having the same issue when calling v2.11 and wondering if it is related to permissions or to deprecation of API endpoints.